# Showing content while ctrl-tabbing through vscode tabs?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

Holding `ctrl` and hitting `tab` in vscode brings up a list of all open tabs in the current view, and hitting `tab` repeatedly advances the selection in this list. Finally, releasing `ctrl` activates the tab that is currently selected in the list.

Is there a way to have `ctrl+tab` "directly" cycle tabs, ie showing/previewing the content of the selected tab while cycling through the list?

I would like that since sometimes I take notes in files with autogenerated filenames, which are not easily recognizable in the list.

(I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.)

Comment: why don't you use `Ctrl+PageUp/PageDown`

Comment: @rioV8 ahh I didn't know about that! that seems to work apart from the fact  that it seems to cycle through all views. do you happen to know if there's a setting making it cycle only the active view? (I mean when working with a split window with two open files next to each other)

Comment: nvm, I think I figured it out. ctrl+pagedown is bound to "view: open next editor", and there is also a function called "view: open next editor in group", so I can remap the shortcut to that. thanks!

Comment: @rioV8 if you write an answer I'll accept it! (unless the question gets deleted before ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can choose any of the following commands:

- **View: Open Next Editor**:
  "key": "ctrl+pagedown", "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor"
- **View: Open Next Editor in Group**:
  "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+pagedown", "command": "workbench.action.nextEditorInGroup"
- **View: Open Next Recently Used Editor**:
  "command": "workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditor"
- **View: Open Next Recently Used Editor In Group**:
  "command": "workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup"

You can bind any key combo to any of these commands.